# MaterialRefreshLayout: how to finishRefreshLoadMore() inside of the onRefreshLoadMore() method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am testing out this library [MaterialRefreshLayout](https://github.com/android-cjj/Android-MaterialRefreshLayout). One problem I have though is I want to be able to end the refresh animation inside the `onRefreshLoadMore()` method like this:

```
materialRefreshLayout = (MaterialRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id...);
 materialRefreshLayout.setMaterialRefreshListener(new MaterialRefreshListener() {
      @Override
      public void onRefresh(final MaterialRefreshLayout materialRefreshLayout) {
          //refreshing...
      }

       @Override
       public void onRefreshLoadMore(MaterialRefreshLayout materialRefreshLayout) {
           materialRefreshLayout.finishRefreshLoadMore();
       }
  }
```

However, I noticed that if I do that the `onRefreshLoadMore()` method fires several times (like 3-4 times). I guess I am not supposed to use the `finishRefreshMore()` method inside of `onRefreshLoadMore()`? Is there some other way to cancel the refreshing animation inside that method?

I want to do this because if I am at the end of my list of data from the backend database, I want to not make anymore network calls and just pop up a Toast telling my user there is no more data. But if I do that now, the Toast runs like 3-4 times... Not sure if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
materialRefreshLayout = (MaterialRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id...);
 materialRefreshLayout.setMaterialRefreshListener(new MaterialRefreshListener() {
      @Override
      public void onRefresh(final MaterialRefreshLayout  
   materialRefreshLayout) {
          //refreshing...

          // Set this to true because it may have been set to false 
          materialRefreshLayout.setLoadMore(true);
      }

       @Override
       public void onRefreshLoadMore(MaterialRefreshLayout materialRefreshLayout) {
           materialRefreshLayout.finishRefreshLoadMore();
           // Set it so that you cannot use pull up to refresh load more anymore
           materialRefreshLayout.setLoadMore(false);
       }
  }
```

What I am doing is disabling the ability to load more data. This stops `onRefreshLoadMore()` from firing over and over. But you have to remember to enable it again in `onRefresh()` or it will be disabled.